# Python Pandas .any() function not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium

I am having a little trouble with the .any() function in my if statement below.

Can somebody please tell me where I messed up ?

Thanks a lot !!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import pandas as pd


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'chromedriver.exe',options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://website.com")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/section/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/button[1]')))
element.click()
time.sleep(5)

network_logs = driver.execute_script("return window.performance.getEntries()")
network_logs
```

[{'activationStart': 0,
'connectEnd': 2846.5999999996275,
'connectStart': 2846.5999999996275,
'decodedBodySize': 96612,
'domComplete': 4661.0999999996275,
'domContentLoadedEventEnd': 3870.199999999255,
'domContentLoadedEventStart': 3833.0999999996275,
'domInteractive': 3833.0999999996275,
'domainLookupEnd': 2846.5999999996275,
'domainLookupStart': 2846.5999999996275,
'duration': 4662,
'encodedBodySize': 14872,
'entryType': 'navigation',
'fetchStart': 2846.5999999996275,
'initiatorType': 'navigation',
'loadEventEnd': 4662,
'loadEventStart': 4661.199999999255,
'name': 'https://www.website.com/',
'nextHopProtocol': 'h2',
'redirectCount': 0,
'redirectEnd': 0,
'redirectStart': 0,
'renderBlockingStatus': 'blocking',
'requestStart': 2874.9000000003725,
'responseEnd': 3095.699999999255,
'responseStart': 2933.699999999255,
'secureConnectionStart': 2846.5999999996275,
'serverTiming': [],
'startTime': 0,
'transferSize': 15172,
'type': 'navigate',
'unloadEventEnd': 0,
'unloadEventStart': 0,
'workerStart': 0},
{'connectEnd': 0,
'connectStart': 0,
'decodedBodySize': 0,
'domainLookupEnd': 0,
'domainLookupStart': 0,
'duration': 145.7999999988824,
'encodedBodySize': 0,
'entryType': 'resource',
'fetchStart': 4111.4000000003725,
'initiatorType': 'xmlhttprequest',
'name': 'https://data.website.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=G-WPY57YJNRN&gtm=2rebu0&_p=2060287772&gcs=G100&gcd=G100&adr=1&cid=44942227.1671145406&ul=en-us&sr=800x600&_fplc=0&_rnd=1960179979.1671145406&uaa=&uab=&uafvl=&uamb=0&uam=&uap=&uapv=&uaw=0&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w.com%ebsite2F&sid=1671145406&sct=1&seg=0&dt=website%w%2website0-%20Google%20Tag%20Manager%20and%20Google%20Analytics&en=page_view&_fv=1&_nsi=1&_ss=1&ep.content_group2=homepage&ep.cd_referrer=&ep.event_id=1671145405112_21_gtm.dom&richsstsse',
'nextHopProtocol': '',
'redirectEnd': 0,
'redirectStart': 0,
'renderBlockingStatus': 'non-blocking',
'requestStart': 0,
'responseEnd': 4257.199999999255,
'responseStart': 0,
'secureConnectionStart': 0,
'serverTiming': [],
'startTime': 4111.4000000003725,
'transferSize': 0,
'workerStart': 0},...

```
df = pd.DataFrame(network_logs)
if df['name'].str.contains('collect?v=2&tid=G-').any():
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

This is returning False. Is there something wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str.contains()` function is defaulted `regex=True`, which means it treats some characters as symbols and not as characters.
Try `df['name'].str.contains('collect?v=2&tid=G-', regex=False)`